# Clash of clans switching accounts on 1 device with two

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have an iphone and an ipad, both of which are logged on to the same gamecenter account. (Same clash of clans). I have a different Apple ID I would like to put on one of them to sort of start over but I would like to keep the other account on the other device. When I try to switch ID's on my ipad it says this current game will be lost. Will it be removed from my iphone? Its sort of  stupid question, I would guess it wouldnt delete it from the other device but I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

No, if you are logged into Gamecenter on the device you want to keep your game save for, your game should be safe. If you want to delete the account on the other device, then you should just be able to log out of your Gamecenter, re install clash of Clans, and have a new account without damaging your other account. Hope this answers your question!